# Pandas ExcelWriter & Win32: How to save pd.df to a password-protected Excel?

Tags: pandas, excel

I want to save a df into multiple sheets of a password-protected Excel file. I have the below code. But there are errors:

1. It doesn't work when I use rf'{url}{filename}.xlsx to OPEN/SaveAS in the WIN32COM section. But it works when I provide the exact filename.
2. How do I suppress the "Select Sensitivity Label" prompt at the part "excel.Workbooks.Open"? Or could be at the part SaveAS.

Thank you

```
import pandas as pd
import win32com.client as win32

def save_excel (df, url, filename):
    
    chunk_size =1000000
    num=1
    frames={}

    for i in range (0, len(df), chunk_size):
        df_subset = df.iloc[i:i + chunk_size]
        frames['Sheet'+str(num)]=df_subset
        num+=1
            
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(rf'{url}\{filename}.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
    
  
    for sheet, frame in  frames.items(): # .use .items for python 3.X
        frame.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = sheet)
    
    writer.save()
    del writer
    
    # USE WIN32COM
    excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
  
    excel.DisplayAlerts = False
    wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(rf'{url}\{filename}.xlsx', UpdateLinks=0)
    #wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(r'C:Desktop\TEST.xlsx') 
    wb.SaveAs(rf'{url}\{filename}.xlsx', Password = 'Pass')   
    #wb.SaveAs(r'C:Desktop\TEST.xlsx', Password = 'Pass')                                             
    wb.Close() 
    excel.Application.Quit()
```